# Simple web crawler in Python3 not producing output. What's going on?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm having issues running the example code listed here: https://dev.to/pranay749254/build-a-simple-python-web-crawler.

This is the code I'm attempting to run:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def web(page,WebUrl):
    if(page>0):
        url = WebUrl
        code = requests.get(url)
        plain = code.text
        s = BeautifulSoup(plain, "html.parser")
        for link in s.findAll('a', {'class':'s-access-detail-page'}):
            tet = link.get('title')
            print(tet)
            tet_2 = link.get('href')
            print(tet_2)
web(1,'https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Stomp+box&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3AStomp+box')
```

When I run the above code through the terminal shell (I'm running Ubuntu 16.04) the program returns no output. I use the following command:

```
$ python3 BasicCrawler.py
```

I press enter, and no text is printed to the terminal, as though I hadn't run any script. I'm able to add print() commands inside the program to verify that it is running, but it doesn't seem to print the variables tet or tet2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went into shell_plus and ran your code with a couple of prints:

```
In [9]: import requests
   ...: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   ...: def web(page,WebUrl):
   ...:     if(page>0):
   ...:         print('page is greater than zero')
   ...:         url = WebUrl
   ...:         code = requests.get(url)
   ...:         plain = code.text
   ...:         s = BeautifulSoup(plain, "html.parser")
   ...:         # hmm, no results
   ...:         #for link in s.findAll('a', {'class':'s-access-detail-page'}):
   ...:         # lets try more open query path to see if we get hits
   ...:         for link in s.findAll('a'):
   ...:             print('link: ', link)
   ...:             tet = link.get('title')
   ...:             print(tet)
   ...:             tet_2 = link.get('href')
   ...:             print(tet_2)
   ...: web(1,'https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&
   ...: field-keywords=Stomp+box&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3AStomp+box')
```

What I found was that the original code had no results, so no output. Then, I changed the input to findAll to just find a tags and got results, so I am guessing the target page does not at this time actually have any a tags with class "s-access-detail-page"?

Comment: that URL returns a status code of 503; there are, in fact, no 'a' tags with that class in them.  You're faster than I was at testing.  I'd recommend checking for the status_code of the URL before you try the for loop.  IF code.status_code == 200 :

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a User-Agent header. Also, for method I am using you cannot have compound class names used in CSS selector so spaces must be replaced with ".". I also complete the relative links.

In your code you would need something like:

```
code = requests.get(url,  headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
```

My version:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

re = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Stomp+box&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3AStomp+box', headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} )
print(re.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(re.content, 'lxml')
base = 'https://www.amazon.com'
links = [(link['title'] ,link['href']) for link in soup.select("a.a-link-normal.s-access-detail-page.s-color-twister-title-link.a-text-normal" )]
links = [(link[0], base + link[1])  if 'slredirect' in link[1] else link for link in links]
print(links)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not printing anything because the list maybe empty. 
That mean "a" tag of class name "s-access-detail-page" contains nothing in the html doc you are parsing.

print the output of the HTTP response and try to find out exact class on which block you want to iterate and fetch data.